# javacc grammar conflicting tokens

Tags: regex, grammar, javacc

I'm parsing command line arguments for a program
ex: `--param1 value1 --param2 value2`

When the value is a String that is preceded by a dash (-) ex: `--param1 -value1` it's a lexical error. 
How should I modify the grammar to accept inputs like above?

```
<STRING : (["A"-"Z" , "a"-"z" , "0"-"9"])+ >
<PARAMNAME : "--"(<STRING>) >
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html I know noone takes it that serious, nor do I. But if you are free to define command line arguments and there is a sort of standard...why not stick to it?

Comment: @BitTickler I have to support for the -value syntax for the program. I think say for a strange calculator program also this kind of syntax will be needed. ( --add 5 --multiplyby -2 --add -10 --divideby 12)

Comment: add `-?` before the `[` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "a value precedes a dash". In `-value`, doesn't the value follow the dash?

Comment: Also, doesn't `-value` already give a lexical error?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Thanks I have edited. I meant a "string preceded by a dash" . ex : --add 5 is accepted  (param=add, value=5) . --add -5 is not (param=add , value=-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to this

```
<VALUE: ("-")? <NAME> >
<PARAMNAME : "--" <NAME> >
<#NAME : (["A"-"Z" , "a"-"z" , "0"-"9"])+ >
```